# Problem with WordPress query on page using custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, genesis-theme-framework

I have a website with the custom post type *sammenligne*, along with some custom fields made using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). I have modified an archive site (archive-sammenligne.php) which displays the data the way I want it, however when I try to extract the data using a WP query on a page, I get no output. If I use the standard WordPress titles, I get output. I assume there is something with the link to the custom fields; but they work on the archive page.

I need to run the query on a WordPress *page*, not an archive, as I would like to have post content above the loop. The code below is saved as a page template.

I run Genesis Metro Pro and WordPress.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
function sk_display_custom_fields() {
/*Custom fields/*
    $navn = get_field( 'navn' );
    $type = get_field( 'type' );
    $fordeler = get_field( 'fordeler' );
/*Wordpress loop*/
    $arg = array(
            'post_type' => 'sammenligne',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
    $query = new WP_Query($arg);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            echo '<h2>' . $navn . '</h2>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query(); 
}
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'sk_display_custom_fields' );

    genesis();
```

Comment: What does your CPT registration looks like? Does it work correctly in other contexts?

Answer (score 1):

Edit ://

try this:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
function sk_display_custom_fields() {
/*Wordpress loop*/
    global $wp_query;
    query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'sammenligne'
    ));

    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
$navn = get_field( 'navn' );
$type = get_field( 'type' );
echo '<p>',$navn , '__', '$type','</p>');
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
}
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'sk_display_custom_fields' );

genesis();
```

UPDATE://

Ok I tested ACF's now. With the following code you can target custom fields of posts from a custom post type without being on an archive site!

```
<?php

    // create custom loop to query the custom posttype
    $arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'sammenligne',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($arg);

// then start the query 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            // now go get the fields you want ! 
            $field1 = get_field('test1');
            // output the fields in the format you want
            echo $field1;
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query(); // reset query
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still can't get it to work. I get a blank page, however if I change the echo in the while loop to something like 'test', I get this printed 4 times, which is the number of sammenligne-posts I have.

Comment: i didnt' notice that your are using ACF. I look into this again in the evening. Perhaps this link helps http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

Comment: i have updated the code. I think you only have to get the fields after u specified the post type in the loop args

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. With the latest change, I just get a blank screen.

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated.

The code you gave me after the edit worked like a charm. I was able to pull all the custom fields. This is like a "related post" roll under my silopages, where I pull posts with custom fields based on another custom field on the pages. When I use this as a page template, I can get a roll with related posts and easily silo my WP sites.

To anyone that googles this later. :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it does work on my other site archive-sammenligne.php, which is the archive file for the slug sammenligne.

This is the output from Advanced Custom Fields. I've removed the other fields (I have abut 20).

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_kredittkort',
        'title' => 'Kredittkort',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_5412c743d82aa',
                'label' => 'Navn',
                'name' => 'navn',
                'type' => 'text',
                'required' => 1,
                'default_value' => '',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'formatting' => 'html',
                'maxlength' => '',
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'field_5412c7e2d82ad',
                'label' => 'Maksgrense',
                'name' => 'maksgrense',
                'type' => 'number',
                'default_value' => '',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'min' => '',
                'max' => '',
                'step' => '',
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'sammenligne',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'acf_after_title',
            'layout' => 'no_box',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}
```